React-Quill: Cursor jumps to top when click toolbar
my issue like that https://i.sstatic.net/RGQ6Y.gif
i'm using React-Quill
I try another libary such as: Drafjs, TipTap, .... but i have still that issue
How fix it?
i try like that :
var quill = new Quill('#editor', {
  modules: { toolbar: toolbarOptions },
    theme: 'snow',
    scrollingContainer: 'body'
});

hmmm it don't work for me
